# Split character vector into named list of character vectors

Tags: r, list

I would like to convert the following character vector into a named list of character vectors, for example:

```r
c(
"Colon and Rectal Surgery", 
"Colon and Rectal Surgery|78|110|82|49|61|79|74.4|96.3|783|1,108|3", 
"Internal Medicine", 
"Cardiovascular Disease|497|1,119|729|168|425|719|58.3|98.6|3,862|6,152|7", 
"Endocrinology, Diabetes, and Metabolism|118|364|233|115|102|218|43.8|93.6|591|1,499|12", 
"Gastroenterology|320|655|383|157|251|362|65.5 94.5|2,256|3,250|15", 
"Hematology|53|128|21|5|11|21|52.4 100.0|58|146|0", 
"Hematology and Oncology|296|741|458|124|238|450|52.0 98.3|1,656|3,511|5", 
"Infectious Disease|130|314|314|128|124|267|39.5 85.0|674|1,770|35", 
"Nephrology|97|510|380|146|92|345|24.2 90.8|494|2,707|24", 
"Oncology|47|168|37|12|9|33|24.3 89.2|56|224|2", 
"Pulmonary Disease|2|72|21|11|1|20|4.8 95.2|2|118|1", 
"Pulmonary Disease and Critical Care Medicine|216|616|417|122|190|404|45.6 96.9|1,099|2,963|7", 
"Rheumatology|89|225|184|102|80|163|43.5|88.6|521|1,162|17", 
"Medical Genetics", 
"Medical Genetics|12|23|53|36|8|15|15.1|28.3|44|99|28"
)
```

would look like:

```
list(
"Colon and Rectal Surgery" = "Colon and Rectal Surgery|78|110|82|49|61|79|74.4|96.3|783|1,108|3", 
"Internal Medicine" = c(
    "Cardiovascular Disease|497|1,119|729|168|425|719|58.3|98.6|3,862|6,152|7", 
    "Endocrinology, Diabetes, and 
     Metabolism|118|364|233|115|102|218|43.8|93.6|591|1,499|12", 
    "Gastroenterology|320|655|383|157|251|362|65.5 94.5|2,256|3,250|15", 
    "Hematology|53|128|21|5|11|21|52.4 100.0|58|146|0", 
    "Hematology and Oncology|296|741|458|124|238|450|52.0 98.3|1,656|3,511|5", 
    "Infectious Disease|130|314|314|128|124|267|39.5 85.0|674|1,770|35", 
    "Nephrology|97|510|380|146|92|345|24.2 90.8|494|2,707|24", 
    "Oncology|47|168|37|12|9|33|24.3 89.2|56|224|2", 
    "Pulmonary Disease|2|72|21|11|1|20|4.8 95.2|2|118|1", 
    "Pulmonary Disease and Critical Care Medicine|216|616|417|122|190|404|45.6|96.9|1,099|2,963|7", 
    "Rheumatology|89|225|184|102|80|163|43.5|88.6|521|1,162|17"
), 
"Medical Genetics" = "Medical Genetics|12|23|53|36|8|15|15.1|28.3|44|99|28"
)
```

I will then easily be able to convert this into a list of named data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the posted vector `vec`. Find where in the vector there are `"|"`, these are the output list members, its names are at the negation of this logical index. A `cumsum` trick plus `rle` gives the lengths of the output list's members and can be used to create the grouping variable `f`.

```r
i <- !grepl("\\|", vec)
f <- rep(vec[i], rle(cumsum(i))$lengths - 1)
split(vec[!i], f)
#> $`Colon and Rectal Surgery`
#> [1] "Colon and Rectal Surgery|78|110|82|49|61|79|74.4|96.3|783|1,108|3"
#> 
#> $`Internal Medicine`
#>  [1] "Cardiovascular Disease|497|1,119|729|168|425|719|58.3|98.6|3,862|6,152|7"                    
#>  [2] "Endocrinology, Diabetes, and Metabolism|118|364|233|115|102|218|43.8|93.6|591|1,499|12"      
#>  [3] "Gastroenterology|320|655|383|157|251|362|65.5 94.5|2,256|3,250|15"                           
#>  [4] "Hematology|53|128|21|5|11|21|52.4 100.0|58|146|0"                                            
#>  [5] "Hematology and Oncology|296|741|458|124|238|450|52.0 98.3|1,656|3,511|5"                     
#>  [6] "Infectious Disease|130|314|314|128|124|267|39.5 85.0|674|1,770|35"                           
#>  [7] "Nephrology|97|510|380|146|92|345|24.2 90.8|494|2,707|24"                                     
#>  [8] "Oncology|47|168|37|12|9|33|24.3 89.2|56|224|2"                                               
#>  [9] "Pulmonary Disease|2|72|21|11|1|20|4.8 95.2|2|118|1"                                          
#> [10] "Pulmonary Disease and Critical Care Medicine|216|616|417|122|190|404|45.6 96.9|1,099|2,963|7"
#> [11] "Rheumatology|89|225|184|102|80|163|43.5|88.6|521|1,162|17"                                   
#> 
#> $`Medical Genetics`
#> [1] "Medical Genetics|12|23|53|36|8|15|15.1|28.3|44|99|28"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>